# How does caffe compute gradient when there are multiple branches?

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, deep-learning, gradient, caffe

I'm now reading `Caffe` source code, and the question occurred to me.

Take `caffe/relu_layer.cpp` for example. When computing gradient, from

```
void ReLULayer<Dtype>::Backward_cpu(const vector<Blob<Dtype>*>& top,
    const vector<bool>& propagate_down,
    const vector<Blob<Dtype>*>& bottom) {
  if (propagate_down[0]) {
    const Dtype* bottom_data = bottom[0]->cpu_data();
    const Dtype* top_diff = top[0]->cpu_diff();
    Dtype* bottom_diff = bottom[0]->mutable_cpu_diff();
    const int count = bottom[0]->count();
    Dtype negative_slope = this->layer_param_.relu_param().negative_slope();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
      bottom_diff[i] = top_diff[i] * ((bottom_data[i] > 0)
          + negative_slope * (bottom_data[i] <= 0));
    }
  }
}
```

we can see a value is finally assigned to `bottom_diff`, indicating that value is the gradient of the corresponding bottom blob.

However, when multiple layers take one blob as inputs, e.g., stacking multiple `ReLU` layers on one blob, how does `Caffe` handle the gradient computation? The first `ReLU` layer modifies `bottom_diff`, and it seems that the second `ReLU` layer just overrides it, instead of adding two gradients.

I didn't see anywhere performing gradient summation, and I am confuses. Please inform me if I have missed something important, and thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Caffe automatically inserts Split layer when a top blob is used in multiple bottoms.  This is done inside `Net<Dtype>::Init(...)` by a call to `InsertSplits(...)` from `caffe/utils/insert_splits.cpp`.

Example:

Original network in `NetParameter` protobuf object (nodes here are layers):

```
data ---> conv1 -> conv2 -> ...
      \-> somelayer -> ...
```

`Net` `Layer`s in memory after `Net::Init()`:

```
data -> split ---> conv1 -> conv2 -> ...
               \-> somelayer -> ...
```

(An interesting detail, by the way: `.diff` in activation `Blobs` is assigned to by `Backward()`, while `.diff` in layer learnable parameters is added to by `Backward()`.)